# jQuery pop up window in background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with `id="icontainer"` in my web page and when the user clicks on it a new url opens in a new tab and the user stays there in the new tab.

How it is possible when the user clicks on my div the new url is opening in background of the browser, or a new tab, but the user remains in my web page?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icontainer").click(function() {
        $("#icontainer").hide();
        var link = 'http://www.youtube.com/42/16022/15176/" alt="" border="0">';
        var mer_window = window.open(link, '_blank', 'toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,status=1,menubar=1');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but it would definately make for a nasty UX, just my 2cents

Comment: Yea i noticed the post but it doesnt work... So any ideas?

Comment: Please don't do this.

Comment: i want to try it @scott.korin is there any possibility to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a popunder. I highly recommend you dont do this. I have never seen a good reason to do this.

If need be, heres a site explaining the code.

Vanilla
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471241/So-You-Want-A-Pop-Under-Window-Huh.htm

jQuery
https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder